# How can I use Fortran libraries from Java?

Tags: java, fortran

For my project I need a Java library which could  solve differential algebraic equation. But I was not able to find it in Java, but I found it in Fortran. How could I use these Fortran library in Java, I am trying to make a applet.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are:

1. If it's simple, translate the code you've found into Java (probably not what you want in this case);
2. Find a Java library that does the same thing;
3. Use the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (though this is [rumored](http://rickyclarkson.blogspot.com/2010/01/jni-applets-pain.html) to be a pain for applets).

Generally 2 is the easiest, if such a library exists.

Comment: I searched it,but their was no such  java library.

Comment: You could always make a server-side app that uses JNI to handle the computation and have the applet call it as a service.